# javascript - import function from within script directly written in the script tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to import functions from a file using the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    import {fn1, fn2} from './file.js';
    // here I continue writing my script
</script>
```

However i receive an error in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

I tried plenty of things,

like import the script `./file.js` in a a separate `<script type='module' src='./file.js'>`,

or using `export {fn1, fn2}` at the end of the `file.js` but nothing works... Can anyone help me out? how can i import few function within a script tab ?

Comment: No browser except Webkit-/Blink-based browsers supports `import`. https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import

Comment: @connexo I am using chrome latest version (67) though

Comment: Latest Chrome version is 69. Show `file.js`.

Comment: @connexo file.js could simply contains `let fn1 = function(x) {console.log(x*x)} let fn2 = function(x) {console.log(x*x*x)}`

Comment: It must read `export function fn1(x) { console.log(x*x); }`.

Comment: @connexo I had tried putting at the end of the file `export {req_prices, reg_news}`. I ll try your suggestion now

Comment: No its still the same

Comment: I hope you're not trying using `file://` protocol.

Comment: i dont know what this is. I just started learning js. But what i have is really whats in the question

Comment: Copy the URL of your test page from the browser and paste it here. CTRL-L, then CTRL-C, here CTRL-V. The URL needs to start with http.

Comment: it's not a online page, therefore the url just directs to the file on my local. Also, if i change the `script` tag to `script type='module'>` i do indeed receive an error showing file//. the error is `Access to Script at 'file:///home/vincent/wintergreen/05_visu/db_post_requests.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: You need a webserver serving your files. File access via Javascript without a webserver using the `file://` protocol is restricted due to security reasons. You have node.js and npm installed and working?

Comment: @connexo Hmm ok thx. Im only using javascript and browser to create visualisation with plotly/d3. Its not meant to ever be online. I thought it would simplify me the task to do it with javascript and html but i might have ebeen misguided. Yes i could use node but i think it might be overkill for what i am trying to do

Comment: I'm asking because node.js allows for very easy setup of a test webserver.

Comment: I had made a test with node js before as i need a server anyway as i use a mondb database. Eventually i settled for a bottle python server as it was even more barebone and i am more familiar with python. But i ll have a second look at node

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181041/discussion-between-connexo-and-jim-basquiat).